# Position element without using absolute positioning

Tags: html, css, css-position

I have the following requirements:

- a `<p>` element filled with text
- a `<img>` element
- the coordinates (x/y) where to position the image

Now I want to position the `<img>` element according to my server side calculated x and y pixel values. I do not want to use `position:absolute` because I also want the text inside the `<p>` element to wrap itself around the image.

[JsFiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/dnmbpa7f/)

Css only would be nice, but using javascript is also possible.

Comment: You can't do this as the flow only wraps around floating elements, but floating elements, or even relative ones for that matter, never allow text flow to be _all around_, only on the other side. Also, this isn't very versatile at all. What if I have a screen that 1000px and your images is 600 wide? Now I've got to scroll to the right...

Comment: in your fiddle the <img> is outside of the <p> tag. as @somethinghere says you'd need to float them... but if you want the text to wrap, you need the <img> to be inside the <p>.

Comment: @somethinghere The server calculates the values correctly, so that this case never happens.

Comment: Your server can't know my screen size.

Comment: @jammypeach thats the problem. Since those two elements get rendered on the server and come from different sources it is impossible to place the <img> inside the <p>.

Comment: @somethinghere sure if your client tells him ;)

Comment: @jammyeach even so, floating them means you can't position it from the top left without creating whitespace on the left and the top/margin will push the text away, positioning will do the same. You can't place an image in the middle of a text block at an arbitrary position without leaving whitespace on the sides. Florian, if it's for a single client, what's the point? :D And lastly, placing the `img` inside the `p` is trivial to do, even server side. Even if its just using php to do `str_replace("</p>","<img></p>","<p>text</p>");` or even using a DOM parser.

Comment: @somethinghere ok placing it inside the `p` would be possible, but how should I know where? I get a text, an image and its size & position from the server. Now I have to build an article like element with the image exactly at the position the server tells me. Even if I place the `img` inside the `p` element, I wouldn't be able to position it exactly at coordinate x/y. To make it short, its a damn complex product for hundred of clients which has grown over the years and I have to implement a new feature.^^

Comment: @FlorianGl I only mentioned that placing it inside the `<p>` is trivial - I also mentioned (and you seem to blissfully ignore) that you can't do this :D (at least consistently and variable-y, the answer below will work but it's not very... consistent. It feels unpredictable.)

Comment: @somethinghere just because you don't know a solution doesn't mean it is impossible. Maybe there is another way the get with the given requirements the desired result, but simply saying "you can't do this" is ignorant.

Comment: @FlorianGl I don't believe they are being ignorant. In some cases, the real answer *is* "you can't do this". This question as stated would probably get the same answer from me - yes there is an answer but it bends the requirements in order to work (and the answerer does say "almost"). Hopefully it will work for you, or you find another solution - good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably one solution for your problem could be the usage of shape-outside with a polyfill for older versions of IE/FF/Chrome.

I've added some code to your example:
http://jsfiddle.net/dnmbpa7f/4/

```css
img{
    shape-outside: polygon(10px 200px, 10px 500px, 550px 500px, 550px 200px);
    shape-margin: 1em;
    margin:25px;
    float:left;
    margin-top:200px;
}

div#container{
    clear:both;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    
<img src="https://www.estella-kochlust.de/media/image/thumbnail/burger_520x520.png"/>  
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,   consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, <span>popop</span>sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
        
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
    
    </p>
</div>
```

For further infos about the polyfill see: http://blogs.adobe.com/webplatform/2014/05/12/css-shapes-polyfill/

Best regards,
Ionic

Comment: You can grab the sourcecode at: https://github.com/adobe-webplatform/css-shapes-polyfill (Sorry just can't post 2 links due to low reputation)

Answer (score 1):

Something that almost works in the toy case is this:

1. Get the full text of the `<p>` element
2. Depending on `x` form 0 to the length of text split the content in a "before", "after" `<span>` elements.
3. Do a dichotomic search to find the `x` splitting point so that `after.offsetTop` is the expected value.
4. Create the final content by adding the span before, the image and the span after.

In code:

```
function add(img, textdiv, y) {
    var t = textdiv.textContent;
    var a = 0, b = t.length;
    var bef = document.createElement("span");
    var aft = document.createElement("span");
    while (a < b-1) {
        var x = (a + b) >> 1;
        bef.textContent = t.substr(0, x);
        aft.textContent = t.substr(x);
        textdiv.innerHTML = "";
        textdiv.appendChild(bef);
        textdiv.appendChild(aft);
        if (aft.offsetTop > y) {
            b = x;
        } else {
            a = x;
        }
    }
    textdiv.innerHTML = "";
    textdiv.appendChild(bef);
    textdiv.appendChild(img);
    textdiv.appendChild(aft);
}
```

Something that is missing from this solution but not hard to add is moving the detected split point to next word boundary (currently it could split the text in the middle of a word).

With both google chrome and firefox I don't see any flicker (but I've done this call only once, not under a timer).

In a real case where it's not just text but arbitrary HTML things are much more complex.

Comment: Thanks, very nice solution, but not suitable for me. I have more than one image and also span and a elements inside the paragraph. I think I have to go a step deeper and change the requirements.

Answer (score 0):

After hours of trying and failing I decided `shapes-polyfill` doesn't fit my needs. Thats why I build my own solution (inspired by `shapes-polyfill`) which you can have a look at [here](http://jsfiddle.net/gh70jecc/).

Cause we are using jQuery I build a solution which uses it, but it can easily be turned into plain javascript (all I use jQuery for is to set some css and append html). Also it is quick and dirty and could be refactored, but atm I am to lazy to do so. ;)